# iPhone skips over non-text form fields

Tags: iphone

When using an iPhone to fill out a form, I hit the Next button on top of the keyboard to navigate from one field to the next. Non-text fields such as lookup and radio are skipped right over to the next text field. A dropdown field however, can be accessed with Next/Previous. How to prevent this from happening?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a general user question?

Comment: I am a mobile site developer. I want to resolve this issue for my site by adding some script. Does it possible?